# Matlab storing values in array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would like to read an image pixel by pixel and store how many of each pixel value there are (grayscale 0-255):

```
img = imread('jetplaneCor.jpg');
imgGray = rgb2gray(img);
sizex = size(imgGray,1);
sizey = size(imgGray,2);
grayArray = [0:0:255]; %Not working

for i=0:1:sizex
   for j=0:1:sizey
       pixelValue = imgGray(i,j);
       grayArray(pixelValue)=grayArray(pixelValue)+1;
   end
end
```

How can i allocate an array with 256 places?

Comment: You should use initialize `grayArray` as `zeros(1,256)`. But see my solution, which is much faster than using two loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a `1 x 256` array where every entry is a `0`:

```
grayArray = zeroes(1, 256);
```

You can reference each element with:

```
grayArray(1, index);
```

Comment: How can i hist grayArray once its filled in.  When i use hist(grayArray) i dont get the right data.

Comment: Have you tried `hist(transpose(grayArray))`? Or you can reverse what I told you and use `grayArray = zeroes(256, 1)` and reference an element with `grayArray(index, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily with [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/hist.html). No need to use loops:

```
img = imread('jetplaneCor.jpg');
imgGray = rgb2gray(img);
grayArray = hist(imgGray(:),0:255);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks.  The point of the program is to write what imhist() does and compare it to our code.

Comment: I've just edited my answer, there was a `(:)` missing. As for your code, as I said in my first commnent, you only had to initialize `grayArray` as `zeros(1,256)`.